# ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: type not defined

Tags: julia

I am working in Julia and I'm trying to use Documenter.jl to create a documentation page for Examples.jl and I keep getting this error when I try to run my make.jl file:

ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: type not defined

Here is my code for the make.jl file:

```
using Documenter
using Examples

makedocs(
    sitename = "Examples.jl",
    pages = Any[
        "About" => "index.md",
        "Main" => "main.md",
        "Graphs" => "graphs.md",
        "Utilities" => "utilities.md",
        "Tutorial" => "tutorial.md"
    ]
)
```

Any ideas how to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: You're using a very old sample code.  The problem isn't in the documentation generation, it's in your `Examples` module.  You're probably using pre-1.0 syntax in that.  Instead of `type`, now use `mutable struct`.

Answer (score 3):

As @Matt B. pointed out, `type` is no longer a valid keyword. In Julia 0.x you used to define types as:

```
type foo
    bar
end
```

[Now we use](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/) `struct` or `mutable struct` instead. e.g.

```
struct foo
    bar
end
```

Go through your code and see if you see `type` anywhere.