# Julia : LoadError: UndefVarError: X not defined

Tags: scope, julia

I have a simple code in Julia:

```
X = 1.0
for i=1:3
  X = X*i
end
println("X = ",X)
```

is throwing error : `LoadError: UndefVarError: X not defined`

Why this is happening?

How to define a simple variable in Julia?

A warning is also thrown:

```
Warning: Assignment to `X` in soft scope is ambiguous because a global variable by the same name exists: `X` will be treated as a new local. Disambiguate
by using `local X` to suppress this warning or `global X` to assign to the existing global variable.
```

[here also asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305520/error-loaderror-undefvarerror-type-not-defined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are executing this code in a plain file without any function.
This means X is declared in the main scope, i.e the global scope. This is a special case as this variable will be "seen" from anywhere in your code.

However, by creating a `for` bloc, you are creating a local variable that has the same label as the global variable. This is ambiguous for the compiler, it doesn't know if you try to create a new variable or use the global one. To remove the ambiguity, `local` or `global` keywords are here to specify what you want to do.

To solve your problem without having to specify global or local, (and [avoid performance issues](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables)) you can just declare your code inside a function. That way your variable `X` is already local:

```
function myfactorial()
   X = 1.0
   for i in 1:3
       X = X*i
   end
   println("X = $X")
end
```

Comment: How would you solve this using global and local? Adding ``global X = 1.0`` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Julia has changed how it does this over time.  At one time the REPL and a function worked differently.  The example works perfectly well on Julia 1.8.5.

`X = 1.0` creates a Float64 global variable.  If this variable was not defined in the scope outside the `for` loop, the `for` loop would create a new variable.  However since it is defined, the `for` loop uses this variable.  As a result the last line gives the expected answer `X = 6.0`.

This is the same answer as `myfactorial()` gives.